# How to roll an SQL Database (and subsequent updates) into a ClickOnce publish?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

My application has a client that also uses a local SQL Server database. In the early stages, I want to use clickonce to propagate changes/updates to the app, but without the SQL Server definitions/tables/and in some cases data in the tables, the client will not work.

I will admit that I can't find much on how to use an SQL Server Project type in VS 2012... But that might not even be applicable.

If this is impossible, then am I forced to do some kind of whacky migration script dl'd via web service?

The ClickOnce works fine for the client, BTW, but obviously on any run on a client (other than my dev box, of course), it barfs...

I'm using EF6+, and on my dev box SQL Server 2012, but there is so little data on the client that I could use SQL Server Express, and make that a ClickOnce prerequisite... But again, how do you roll the DB into the update/install(er)?

I must be losing it, because there is precious little I can locate that addresses this seemingly common architecture for deployment...

We used to have Deployment Projects in VS...

Comment: Did you read [this](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2011/02/06/how-about-a-bootstrapper-package-for-sqlserver-express-2008-r2/) article? It should also apply to SQL Server 2012 Express.

Comment: @Herdo, thank you for writing. The link you sent, and the links in them, deal with initial installation, and with changing keys/certs/signing. What I'm talking about is after the pre-requisite SQL DB is in place, how to roll the changes into their environment. I'm using EF6, so Migrations() works for schema. I mean, when there is data in the key app-created tables for the app's ability to run. In other words, a Click-Once would need to not just do the pre-req DB, but also the tables; BOTH initially and on update... Sorry I wasn't more verbose/clear! :)

Comment: Am I understanding this right: You want to run SQL scripts during the initial installation as well as with every update? But not by the app itself on startup?

Comment: @Herdo, essentially, yes. Since I am not permitted by the moderators to ask the best way, I am forced to make the one I _guess_ might be the right way. :(

Comment: Ok. Just one hint here: What happens, when a user skips an update or even more. Couldn't this break your local database? I think running it during the app startup or as background process might be a better idea here. However, if you want to stick with the installation/update part, you'll need to write a custom installer to execute custom SQL scripts.

Comment: @Herdo, Thank you again for writing. I appreciate your interest very much. In EF, changes to DB schema (which reflect changes in entity/class code) are created in order, with datestamp in the filename, and can be sent as complete classes to be run on a client. In ClickOnce, only the client app is re-installed on update. Would there be a way to hook into that process, adding steps to take in code? [I'm walking on egg shells with these questions] Thanks! :)

Comment: As said before, I think you'll need a [custom ClickOnce installer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997001.aspx).